# Why do I get a syntax error after upgrading Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had a working Rails site which I did not touch for some time. I am now opening it in Rails 3.1.0 and Ruby 1.9.2p290.

I have this syntax in my view:

```
<%= form_tag ("save", :method=>"get", :id=>"save") do  %>
```

I now get this Rails error when it process the view:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end):
```

I have read that I should use this instead, but I am not sure why:

```
<%= form_tag :action=>"save", :method=>"get", :id=>"save" do  %>
```

This does render something to the user but it renders a form without an "`id`" attribute like before; it should be "`save`". I found many links suggesting to put the parameters in `{...}` or do other stuff, but the `id` is never generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the space character after the `form_tag` to make it:

```
<%= form_tag("save", :method=>"get", :id=>"save") do  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:action=>"save"), :method=>"get", :id=>"save" do %>
```